# Looking for LDAP (v3) to SAML message converter or bridge

Tags: ldap, saml

I have an authentication/authorization server that currently uses a local ADAM instance to hold the authentication and authorization information for use by a Service Provider (SP).

What I want to do is change from the ADAM instance to a remote ADFS for authentication and authorization.  The remote ADFS talks SAML but the Service Provider (SP) only talks with LDAP (and I cannot change the SP to talk SAML).

This suggests that I need to provide a LDAP to SAML converter (or bridge) to produce SAML messages from the SP's incoming LDAP authentication and authorization requests.

Currently it's like this:

```
          LDAP
  SP <------------> Authentication Server
```

I want it to look like this:

```
          LDAP                                                   SAML
  SP <------------> Authentication Server w/LDAP/SAML bridge <------------> ADFS
```

So essentially the current authentication server will cease to authenticate itself and will
merely act as a "proxy" for passing on authentication/authorization requests and relaying
responses back to the SP.

Is this possible?
Does anyone have experience with this sort of effort?
Are there any tools on the Net that could perform this bridge functionality?

The current authentication/authorization server runs on *gasp* Windows 2003 but I do have the
option of porting it to a newer version of Windows Server.

I have tried using OneLogin with the SAML toolkit/Flask websever, and writing my own Python module for handling the SP's requests but I'm getting bogged down with that code (and exposing my own Python limitations)

I also tried SimpleSAMLphp but determined that the LDAP stuff they support is for the IDP side rather than the SP side.  The system performs SP-side initiatation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [ADFS to LDAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-to-authenticate-users-stored-in-ldap-directories) directly?

Your application would then use [ADAL / MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/enabling-openid-connect-with-ad-fs) to connect.

Comment: Thanks for responding!  Not sure that I fully understand, but the final aim is to move the LDAP authentication information out of the LDAP ADAM instance and into ADFS but we want to retain the LDAP protocol stuff (at least for the short term).

Comment: (cont'd from previous comment) I'm not sure if the link you kindly provided matches what I'm trying to do.  If I port my LDAP data into ADFS, will I be able to access this new  ADFS data using LDAPv3?

Comment: You don't port your data. ADFS normally authenticates against AD. The link above allows ADFS to authenticate against an LDAP. ADFS is a layer above AD. It is not itself a repository.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I understand but what we want to do is incorporate the LDAP data into our AD data forest.  The user names are duplicated on both the AD and LDAP instances but other needed user data exists only on the LDAP side and will eventually be added to the AD side at which point the LDAP side will be removed.